# While generating MS-word file using jasperreports, a text-field is using two lines when it is short enough to be included in a single line

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-word

I have an issue with generating *MS Word* output file - textField is using two lines when it is short enough to be included in a single line:

[image: the issue]

The pdf file is generated as expected (i.e. the entire text-field is in single line )

I'm using jaspersoft studio 6.0.3 to generate the jrxml file used to generate this document.

Below is the jrxml file being used

[jrxml file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r5Rm4arMfVYXp1OleAbai61KdZls8FQl/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Create a minimal, complete, verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was seen in the fields enclosed in frame.
I needed to add the property below to the jrxml file:

`<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.docx.frames.as.nested.tables" value="false"/>`